# Compile for windows using mingw-w64 and autotools

Tags: c, mingw, cross-compiling, autotools, mingw-w64

I've this project called [librsync](https://github.com/librsync/librsync).
Installed ubuntu package called [mingw-w64](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mingw-w64). Looked at automake [manpage](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html).

What I want to do is to build executable that runs on windows or `dll`, whichever I could get working.

`./configure --host "what do i put here?"`

By looking at ubuntu packages I can't figure it out. From automake manpage - If I had `mingw32` it should be `i586-mingw32msvc`. But how do I figure that out on my own in the first place? At least, what should I put in `hosts` param if I have mingw-w64?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For building something with a cross compiler, you will use ***configuration***-gcc as the C compiler with ***configuration*** being what you would pass to `--host` to build a library or executable.

`ls /usr/bin/*mingw*gcc` should give you the C compiler to use, allowing you to know what the ***configuration*** is.

- MinGW (aka mingw32): **iX86-pc-mingw32** or **iX86-mingw32msvc** (X is a 4, 5, or 6 depending on how it was configured)
- mingw-w64: ***ARCH*-w64-mingw32** (*ARCH* is one of i686 or x86_64)

I've honestly not seen anything else for mingw-w64, except in its earlier days when it used *ARCH*-pc-mingw64, but that shouldn't be used anymore.